# Mysql multiple selector

Tags: php, mysql

I can not find out how to join this multiple selectors into one. Any help?

I already try clausule `UNIT` but it does not work ether. It is for filtering purpose in `HTML` (+`php`) form using:

`<input type="text" name="town_from">`

as a enter for text value. They work well separately but not both at once.

```
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM ship_db WHERE town_from = '$town_from' AND town_to = '$town_to' ORDER BY  top DESC, date_time_of_insert DESC";

$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM ship_db WHERE price BETWEEN '$price_from' AND '$price_to' ORDER BY top DESC, date_time_of_insert DESC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT s.*
FROM ship_db s
WHERE (s.town_from = '$town_from' AND s.town_to = '$town_to') OR
      (s.price BETWEEN '$price_from' AND '$price_to')
ORDER BY s.top DESC, s.date_time_of_insert DESC;
```

Notes:

- I am assuming that you want rows that match either criteria (hence `OR`).  If you want both, then use `AND`.
- You should be using parameterized queries.  That is, don't put user input directly into the query.
- Presumably, `price` is a number.  You should compare numbers to numbers and dispense with the single quotes (of course, this is also fixed by using parameters).

Comment: Exactly, just changed OR to AND. Thank you, this was my all day struggle!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not combine the where clause?

```
"SELECT * FROM ship_db 
  WHERE town_from = '$town_from' AND town_to = '$town_to'
  AND price BETWEEN '$price_from' AND '$price_to' 
  ORDER BY  top DESC, date_time_of_insert DESC";
```

or you could try to build it dynamically something like:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM ship_db ";
if(isset($town_from) && isset($town_from)){
  $where = "WHERE town_from = '$town_from' AND town_to = '$town_to'";
}
if(isset($price_from) && isset($price_to)){
  if(isset($where)){
    $where += " AND price BETWEEN '$price_from' AND '$price_to'";
  }else{
    $where = "WHERE price BETWEEN '$price_from' AND '$price_to'";
  }

}

$sql += $where;
$sql += " ORDER BY  top DESC, date_time_of_insert DESC";
```

Comment: This non-dynamical query was not working. I try that before. It was selecting just first or second condition.. not both.